# Error upgrading 2SXC content from 11.03 to 11.04

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc, dnn9

I'm running DNN 9.6.2 in Azure as an App Service app. I have 2SXC content 11.03 installed and running well, but wished to upgrade to 11.04. When attempting to install via Settings-->Extensions-->Install Extension, the installation proceeds but eventually errors out (install log attached). The site using the 2SXC content is no longer viable (the modules no longer display - they are absent from the pages) and the site must be restored from backup to be operational again. After the failed installation, the "installed extensions" page shows 2SXC Content 11.4 installed, while 2SCX App is still at 11.3.

> StartJob Starting InstallationInfo Starting Installation - 2SexyContentInfo Starting Installation - ScriptInfo Begin Sql executionInfo Creating backup of previous version - SqlDataProvider\Uninstall.SqlDataProviderInfo Created - SqlDataProvider\Uninstall.SqlDataProviderInfo Finished Sql executionInfo Component installed successfully - ScriptInfo Starting Installation - CleanupInfo Processing Cleanup File - 11.4.0Info Completed Processing of Cleanup File - 11.4.0Info Component installed successfully - CleanupInfo Starting Installation - ModuleInfo Module registered successfully - 2sxcInfo Component installed successfully - ModuleInfo Starting Installation - AssemblyInfo Assembly updated - bin\ImageResizer.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\ImageResizer.dllInfo Created - bin\ImageResizer.dllInfo Assembly in use by another package - bin\ImageResizer.dllInfo Component installed successfully - AssemblyInfo Starting Installation - AssemblyInfo Assembly already registered - bin\ToSic.SexyContent.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.SexyContent.dllInfo Created - bin\ToSic.SexyContent.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\ToSic.Sxc.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Sxc.dllInfo Created - bin\ToSic.Sxc.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.dllInfo Created - bin\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\ToSic.SexyContent.Razor.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.SexyContent.Razor.dllInfo Created - bin\ToSic.SexyContent.Razor.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\ToSic.SexyContent.WebApi.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.SexyContent.WebApi.dllInfo Created - bin\ToSic.SexyContent.WebApi.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\ToSic.Eav.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Eav.dllInfo Created - bin\ToSic.Eav.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\ToSic.Eav.Apps.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Eav.Apps.dllInfo Created - bin\ToSic.Eav.Apps.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\ToSic.Eav.Core.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Eav.Core.dllInfo Created - bin\ToSic.Eav.Core.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\ToSic.Eav.DataSources.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Eav.DataSources.dllInfo Created - bin\ToSic.Eav.DataSources.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\ToSic.Eav.ImportExport.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Eav.ImportExport.dllInfo Created - bin\ToSic.Eav.ImportExport.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\ToSic.Eav.Persistence.Efc.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Eav.Persistence.Efc.dllInfo Created - bin\ToSic.Eav.Persistence.Efc.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\ToSic.Eav.Repository.Efc.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Eav.Repository.Efc.dllInfo Created - bin\ToSic.Eav.Repository.Efc.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\ToSic.Eav.Tokens.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Eav.Tokens.dllInfo Created - bin\ToSic.Eav.Tokens.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\ToSic.Eav.WebApi.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Eav.WebApi.dllInfo Created - bin\ToSic.Eav.WebApi.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\CsvHelper.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\CsvHelper.dllInfo Created - bin\CsvHelper.dllInfo Binding redirect added for assembly - bin\CsvHelper.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dllInfo Created - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dllInfo Binding redirect added for assembly - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dllInfo Created - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dllInfo Binding redirect added for assembly - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dllInfo Created - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dllInfo Binding redirect added for assembly - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dllInfo Created - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dllInfo Binding redirect added for assembly - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dllInfo Created - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dllInfo Binding redirect added for assembly - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dllInfo Created - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dllInfo Binding redirect added for assembly - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dllInfo Created - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dllInfo Binding redirect added for assembly - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dllInfo Created - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dllInfo Binding redirect added for assembly - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dllInfo Created - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dllInfo Binding redirect added for assembly - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dllInfo Created - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dllInfo Binding redirect added for assembly - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dllInfo Created - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dllInfo Binding redirect added for assembly - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\2sxc\Remotion.Linq.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Remotion.Linq.dllInfo Created - bin\2sxc\Remotion.Linq.dllInfo Binding redirect added for assembly - bin\2sxc\Remotion.Linq.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\2sxc\System.Collections.Immutable.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\System.Collections.Immutable.dllInfo Created - bin\2sxc\System.Collections.Immutable.dllInfo Binding redirect added for assembly - bin\2sxc\System.Collections.Immutable.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\2sxc\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dllInfo Created - bin\2sxc\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dllInfo Binding redirect added for assembly - bin\2sxc\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\2sxc\System.Interactive.Async.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\System.Interactive.Async.dllInfo Created - bin\2sxc\System.Interactive.Async.dllInfo Binding redirect added for assembly - bin\2sxc\System.Interactive.Async.dllInfo Component installed successfully - AssemblyInfo Starting Installation - FileInfo Creating backup of previous version - icon.pngInfo Created - icon.pngInfo Creating backup of previous version - License.txtInfo Created - License.txtInfo Creating backup of previous version - ReleaseNotes.txtInfo Created - ReleaseNotes.txtInfo Component installed successfully - FileInfo Starting Installation - ResourceFileInfo Expanding Resource fileFailure Installation Failed - ResourceFileInfo Rolling back component install - ScriptInfo Restored backup of previous version - SqlDataProvider\Uninstall.SqlDataProviderInfo Component rolled back successfully - ScriptInfo Rolling back component install - CleanupInfo Component rolled back successfully - CleanupInfo Rolling back component install - ModuleInfo Component rolled back successfully - ModuleInfo Rolling back component install - AssemblyInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\ImageResizer.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\ImageResizer.dllInfo Component rolled back successfully - AssemblyInfo Rolling back component install - AssemblyInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.SexyContent.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Sxc.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.SexyContent.Razor.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.SexyContent.WebApi.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Eav.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Eav.Apps.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Eav.Core.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Eav.DataSources.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Eav.ImportExport.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Eav.Persistence.Efc.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Eav.Repository.Efc.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Eav.Tokens.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Eav.WebApi.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\CsvHelper.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\Remotion.Linq.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\System.Collections.Immutable.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dllInfo Restored backup of previous version - bin\2sxc\System.Interactive.Async.dllInfo Component rolled back successfully - AssemblyInfo Rolling back component install - FileInfo Restored backup of previous version - icon.pngInfo Restored backup of previous version - License.txtInfo Restored backup of previous version - ReleaseNotes.txtInfo Component rolled back successfully - FileInfo Installation Failed - 2SexyContentInfo Starting Installation - 2SexyContent-AppInfo Starting Installation - ScriptInfo Begin Sql executionInfo Creating backup of previous version - SqlDataProvider\require-2sxc-9.SqlDataProviderInfo Created - SqlDataProvider\require-2sxc-9.SqlDataProviderInfo Executing require-2sxc-9.SqlDataProviderInfo Start Sql execution: require-2sxc-9.SqlDataProvider fileInfo End Sql execution: require-2sxc-9.SqlDataProvider fileInfo Finished Sql executionInfo Component installed successfully - ScriptInfo Starting Installation - ModuleInfo Module registered successfully - 2sxc-appInfo Component installed successfully - ModuleInfo Starting Installation - FileInfo Creating backup of previous version - icon-app.pngInfo Created - icon-app.pngInfo Component installed successfully - FileInfo Starting Installation - ConfigInfo Creating backup of previous version - web.configInfo Config file updated - web.configInfo Component installed successfully - ConfigInfo Config file changes committed - web.configFailure Package Installation abortedInfo Installation Failed - 2SexyContent-AppInfo Starting Installation - 2sic_Imazen_ImageResizerProInfo Starting Installation - ResourceFileInfo Expanding Resource fileInfo Creating backup of previous version - imageresizer_400_00aec4.pngInfo Created - imageresizer_400_00aec4.pngInfo Resource Files createdInfo Component installed successfully - ResourceFileInfo Starting Installation - AssemblyInfo Assembly already registered - bin\ImageResizer.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\ImageResizer.dllInfo Created - bin\ImageResizer.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.dllInfo Created - bin\ImageResizer.Plugins.DiskCache.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\ImageResizer.Plugins.WebP.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\ImageResizer.Plugins.WebP.dllInfo Created - bin\ImageResizer.Plugins.WebP.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\Imazen.WebP.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\Imazen.WebP.dllInfo Created - bin\Imazen.WebP.dllInfo Component installed successfully - AssemblyInfo Starting Installation - ConfigInfo Creating backup of previous version - web.configInfo Config file updated - web.configInfo Component installed successfully - ConfigInfo Config file changes committed - web.configFailure Package Installation abortedInfo Installation Failed - 2sic_Imazen_ImageResizerProInfo Starting Installation - Connect.Dnn.KoiInfo Starting Installation - ResourceFileInfo Expanding Resource fileInfo Creating backup of previous version - icon.pngInfo Created - icon.pngInfo Creating backup of previous version - License.txtInfo Created - License.txtInfo Creating backup of previous version - ReleaseNotes.txtInfo Created - ReleaseNotes.txtInfo Resource Files createdInfo Component installed successfully - ResourceFileInfo Starting Installation - AssemblyInfo Assembly already registered - bin\Connect.Dnn.Koi.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\Connect.Dnn.Koi.dllInfo Created - bin\Connect.Dnn.Koi.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\Connect.Koi.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\Connect.Koi.dllInfo Created - bin\Connect.Koi.dllInfo Component installed successfully - AssemblyFailure Package Installation abortedInfo Installation Failed - Connect.Dnn.KoiInfo Starting Installation - ToSic.RazorBladeInfo Starting Installation - ResourceFileInfo Expanding Resource fileInfo Creating backup of previous version - icon.pngInfo Created - icon.pngInfo Creating backup of previous version - License.txtInfo Created - License.txtInfo Creating backup of previous version - ReleaseNotes.txtInfo Created - ReleaseNotes.txtInfo Resource Files createdInfo Component installed successfully - ResourceFileInfo Starting Installation - AssemblyInfo Assembly already registered - bin\ToSic.Razor.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Razor.dllInfo Created - bin\ToSic.Razor.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\ToSic.Razor.Dnn.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\ToSic.Razor.Dnn.dllInfo Created - bin\ToSic.Razor.Dnn.dllInfo Component installed successfully - AssemblyFailure Package Installation abortedInfo Installation Failed - ToSic.RazorBladeInfo Starting Installation - Connect.RazorInfo Starting Installation - ResourceFileInfo Expanding Resource fileInfo Creating backup of previous version - icon.pngInfo Created - icon.pngInfo Creating backup of previous version - License.txtInfo Created - License.txtInfo Creating backup of previous version - ReleaseNotes.txtInfo Created - ReleaseNotes.txtInfo Resource Files createdInfo Component installed successfully - ResourceFileInfo Starting Installation - AssemblyInfo Assembly already registered - bin\Connect.Razor.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\Connect.Razor.dllInfo Created - bin\Connect.Razor.dllInfo Assembly already registered - bin\Connect.Razor.Dnn.dllInfo Creating backup of previous version - bin\Connect.Razor.Dnn.dllInfo Created - bin\Connect.Razor.Dnn.dllInfo Component installed successfully - AssemblyFailure Package Installation abortedInfo Installation Failed - Connect.RazorInfo Deleted temporary install folderEndJob Installation Failed

I've attempted to "repair" the installation via Settings-->Extensions-->Install Extension with the same results/errors in the install log.

I don't know if this is a bug in 2SXC, or something in particular about my installation. Similar reports of install issues related to unpacking Resources have led me to verify file/folder permissions on the site, but those seem ok.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to StackOverflow :)

This is not a known issue. It seems to fail installing the resources - which is usually normal files in the `DesktopModules` folder or possibly .pdb files (debug files) in the bin folder.

My guess is that you may have changed security settings like file permissions on the server, which seems to block changes.

For anything else I would need more to go on.